# Insert a year range using Faker in Laravel

Tags: laravel, faker

How can I insert a date like '2017-2018' using faker in laravel.
I can get the year by
`$startYear = $faker->year('now');`

But I want to insert like '2017-2018' or '2018-2019' etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add 1 to the year you got from Faker. E.g.:

```
$startYear = $faker->year('now'); // 2017
$endYear = $startYear  + 1; // 2018
$result = $startYear . "-" . $endYear; // 2017-2018
```